# APScheduler Look up object error

Tags: apscheduler

APScheduler (3.3.1)  py2.7

I use this code to do my job When I use Memory as job store it can work well but I have too many job and my Memory in server is limit so I change SQLAlchemyJobStore as job store but I got the Lookup error. How to solve it.

Code:

```
def script(indicator, strategy_name, real_time=False):
    # Solve No handlers could be found for logger “apscheduler.scheduler
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR,
                        format='%(name)-12s %(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
    try:
        job_defaults = {
            'coalesce': False,
            'max_instances': 1,
            "misfire_grace_time": config.real_time_script_interval + 5,
        }
        executors = {
            'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(60),
        }
        jobstores = {
            "default": SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
        }

        scheduler = BlockingScheduler(daemonic=True, jobstores=jobstores, job_defaults=job_defaults,
                                      executors=executors)
        module = __import__("%s.%s" % (indicator, strategy_name), fromlist=[strategy_name])
        if real_time:
            for st in module.strategy:
                scheduler.add_job(st.run, "interval", seconds=config.real_time_script_interval)
        else:
            for st in module.strategy:
                # 计算最近的下一个准点时间
                start_time = _recent_time(st.run_period)
                scheduler.add_job(st.run, "interval", **start_time)
        scheduler.start()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.get("run-log").error(error_msg())
```

Error:

```
apscheduler.jobstores.default Thu, 06 Apr 2017 10:50:32 ERROR    Unable to restore job "d100a4b24e2d49c3ad51305fd846e5f5" -- removing it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py", line 135, in _get_jobs
    jobs.append(self._reconstitute_job(row.job_state))
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py", line 122, in _reconstitute_job
    job.__setstate__(job_state)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 260, in __setstate__
    self.func = ref_to_obj(self.func_ref)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 277, in ref_to_obj
    raise LookupError('Error resolving reference %s: error looking up object' % ref)
LookupError: Error resolving reference base.strategy:Strategy.run: error looking up object
apscheduler.jobstores.default Thu, 06 Apr 2017 10:50:32 ERROR    Unable to restore job "2602167cd3c745c2b0764a2b63da1a3a" -- removing it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py", line 135, in _get_jobs
    jobs.append(self._reconstitute_job(row.job_state))
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py", line 122, in _reconstitute_job
    job.__setstate__(job_state)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 260, in __setstate__
    self.func = ref_to_obj(self.func_ref)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 277, in ref_to_obj
    raise LookupError('Error resolving reference %s: error looking up object' % ref)
LookupError: Error resolving reference base.strategy:Strategy.run: error looking up object
apscheduler.jobstores.default Thu, 06 Apr 2017 10:50:32 ERROR    Unable to restore job "3eb917670e7642b8848a165268df8913" -- removing it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py", line 135, in _get_jobs
    jobs.append(self._reconstitute_job(row.job_state))
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py", line 122, in _reconstitute_job
    job.__setstate__(job_state)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 260, in __setstate__
    self.func = ref_to_obj(self.func_ref)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 277, in ref_to_obj
    raise LookupError('Error resolving reference %s: error looking up object' % ref)
LookupError: Error resolving reference base.strategy:Strategy.run: error looking up object
```

**Supplementary instruction** for Alex Grönholm's question here because it is hard to say in comment

In base/strategy_util.py:

**base_strategy** is some classes which **inherit** the BaseStrategy class  in **base/strategy.py** . The BaseStrategy has its **run** method

```
def _strategy(base_strategy, minute, ticker_table_format):
    class Strategy(base_strategy):
        run_period = minute

        def _init_params(self):
            self.ticker_table_format = ticker_table_format

    return Strategy()


def _create_strategy(base_strategy, minute_list=ALL_MINUTE):
    strategy_list = []
    for minute in minute_list:
        for ticker_table_format in const.TICKER_TABLE_FORMAT.ALL:
            st = _strategy(base_strategy, minute, ticker_table_format)
            strategy_list.append(st)
    return strategy_list


def ma_strategy(base_strategy):
    return _create_strategy(base_strategy)
```

In MA/touch_avg.py:

`MA_TOUCH_AVG` **inherit** the BaseStrategy class

```
from base.strategy import MA_TOUCH_AVG
from base.strategy_util import ma_strategy

strategy = ma_strategy(MA_TOUCH_AVG)
```

And then I use `click` to call the strategy like `python run_strategy.py run MA touch_avg`

In run_strategy.py:

```
@cli.command()
@click.argument('indicator')
@click.argument('strategy_name')
def run(indicator, strategy_name):
    """ run indicator strategy_name """
    real_time_strategy_name = ["touch_avg", "limit"]
    util.script(indicator, strategy_name,
                real_time=strategy_name in real_time_strategy_name)
```

Comment: Do you have a module named `base.strategy` and in it a class named `Strategy` and a method in it named `run()`?

Comment: Hello @AlexGrönholm I add more detail about my question.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're having this problem is because you create a class dynamically, in a function. APScheduler stores the reference to the scheduled function as `module:varname`. How is the scheduler expected to find a class that you're making on the fly in a function?

Comment: I hope I can use another method for serialization instead of cPickle

Comment: Not at the moment you can't. But that has nothing to do with the problem. The scheduler needs to know how to find your scheduled function when it is started.

Comment: This solves my problem! You always define another module and its function to call in `add_job(func)`, while the Scheduler has its class. Thx!